# Changing The Date Values of NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults from a Dictionary Response

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsuserdefaults

My method receives a Dictionary named `responseDict` which contains keys, such as `id`, `status`, `name`, `phoneNumber`, `date` etc. in

```
responseDict[@"data"][@"value"][n]
```

(`n` for number)

If our code uses `NSUserDefaults` to access data:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

How can I change the `date` MySQL attribute `2017-05-12 10:00:00` to `Dec 5, 2017 10 AM`?

I tried the following, but it does not seem to change the `defaults` in the `UILabel`.

```
[defaults setInteger:[dictionary[@"id"] integerValue] forKey:@"ID"];
[defaults setObject:dictionary[@"status"] forKey:kNSUDoctorStatus];
[defaults setInteger:[dictionary[@"dur"] integerValue] forKey:@"duration"];
[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ some",dictionary[@"date"]] forKey:@"date"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

**Edit:**

**UILabel**

The UILabel seems to have been added to the view by:

```
UILabel *vb = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:personMessageViewTag];
```

which was defined by:

```
#define personMessageViewTag 3001
```

**Doctor Class**

There is also a `PersonDetailView` class initialized:

```
PersonDetailView *personOnTheView;
```

And called in a method:

```
personOnTheView = [PersonDetailView sharedInstance];
personOnTheView.delegate = self;
[personOnTheView updateValues];
[self.view addSubview:personOnTheView];
```

**Method:**
Here is the code for `[personOnTheView updateValues]`

```
-(void)updateValues{

    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *strImageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseUrlForXXHDPIImage,[ud objectForKey:kOnGoingBookingPersonProfileImageKey]];
    _doctorName.text = [ud objectForKey:kOnGoingBookingPersonNameKey];

    NSString *at = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",flStrForObj([Helper getLocalDate:[ud objectForKey:kOnGoingBookingPersonBookingDate]])];

    _appoinmentTime.text = at;

     float rating = [[ud objectForKey:kOnGoingBookingPersonRatingKey] floatValue];

    _starRatingView.value = rating;

    [_profilepic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Helper removeWhiteSpaceFromURL:strImageUrl]]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doctor_image_thumbnail"]
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){
                         }];
}
```

**Problem:**

Everytime I change or modify:

```
[defaults setObject:dictionary[kPNPayloadAppoinmentTimeKey] forKey:kOnGoingBookingPersonBookingDate];
```

To:

```
[defaults setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ some",dictionary[@"date"]] forKey:@"date"];
```

or just as simple as:

```
[defaults setObject:@"Something here" forKey:@"date"];
```

It displays blank.

**Additional Information Edit:**

`[Helper getLocalDate]` code:

```
+(NSString *)getLocalDate:(NSString *)gmtdate {

    NSString *dateStr = gmtdate;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *destinationDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatters = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatters setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy HH a"];
    dateStr = [dateFormatters stringFromDate: destinationDate];
    // NSLog(@"DateString : %@", dateStr);
    return dateStr;
}
```

Comment: You say "defaults in the UILabel" above? I don't see any UILabel in the code snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added `UILabel`, `DoctorDetailView`, and method `[docOnTheView updateValues]`

Comment: PersonDetailView, is a singleton? That seems weird. You're not letting iOS manage its lifecycle?

Comment: I was just fixing the problem. The weird thing that I found out yesterday is that there was a `Helper` singleton with the method `getLocalDate` and changes the date from string to date. Then, returns it from date to string (which is even weirder). Adding that method right now.

Comment: I think everything was solved, but it would help if there is another formula to change from `MySQL` date string to custom date string properly. Can you help me change the string date to return custom date format properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of this method you can get the date in local format if you having time zone in date string

```
-(NSDate*)convertDateToLocal:(NSString *)strDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *localFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [localFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
    NSDate *localDate = [localFormat dateFromString:strDate];
    return localDate;
}
```

Here are two public method for date conversion if you don't have time zone

1) Date from string,

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)strSource inFormat:(NSString *)strTargetFormat
{
  NSDateFormatter *dtfFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dtfFormatter setDateFormat:strTargetFormat];

  return [dtfFormatter dateFromString:strSource];
}
```

2) String from date,

```
+ (NSString *)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)dtSourceDate inFormat:(NSString *)strTargetFormat
{
  NSDateFormatter *dtfFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dtfFormatter setDateFormat:strTargetFormat];

  if (dtSourceDate != nil)
    return [dtfFormatter stringFromDate:dtSourceDate];
  else
    return @"";
}
```

Hope this helps.